# Spring Boot : Load property file in constructor and use as autowire annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot application I am trying to load yaml property file and trying to use this class in @Autowire annotation in another class getting null pointer excepton

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Data
public class ServiceGridConfiguration {

    public  AdapterConfig adapterConfig;



    public ServiceGridConfiguration() {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            String yamlFile ="ServiceGrid.yaml";
            try {

                AdapterConfig adapterConfig = yaml.loadAs( ServiceTypeResolver.class.getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream(yamlFile),AdapterConfig.class );
                System.out.println("adapterConfig" + adapterConfig.getSeedGroup());

                 this.adapterConfig = adapterConfig;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in reading adapterConfig file "+yamlFile,e);
            }

    }

    }
```

In above constructor able to print in constructor while loading, but getting null pointer exception when hitting rest endpoint

```
public class ServiceGrid implements IhubStrategy {

    @Autowired
    ServiceGridConfiguration sfg;


    @Override
    public void processRequest(String message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ServiceGrid   "+message+"*******"+sfg.getAdapterConfig().getSeedEntity());
    }

}
```

@Component
public class IhubStrategyFactory {

```
@Autowired
ServiceGridConfiguration sfg;

@Autowired
ServiceGrid sg;

public IhubStrategy getIhubStrategy(String serviceDefinition) {

    System.out.println("IhubStrategyFactory : "+sfg.getAdapterConfig().getSeedEntity());
```

//      IhubStrategy strategy = null;

```
    if (serviceDefinition.equalsIgnoreCase("serviceGrid")) {

        return new ServiceGrid();
        /*try {
            sg.processRequest("serviceGrid");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    } else if (serviceDefinition.equalsIgnoreCase("TopologyResponse")) {
```

//          strategy = new TopologyResponse();
        }

```
    return null;
}
```

}

```
@Component
public class IhubStrategyFactory {

    @Autowired
    ServiceGridConfiguration sfg;

    @Autowired
    ServiceGrid sg;

    public IhubStrategy getIhubStrategy(String serviceDefinition) {

        System.out.println("IhubStrategyFactory : "+sfg.getAdapterConfig().getSeedEntity());

//      IhubStrategy strategy = null;

        if (serviceDefinition.equalsIgnoreCase("serviceGrid")) {

            return new ServiceGrid();
            /*try {
                sg.processRequest("serviceGrid");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

        } else if (serviceDefinition.equalsIgnoreCase("TopologyResponse")) {
//          strategy = new TopologyResponse();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Service instead of Component.

Comment: `ServiceGrid` should be annotated with service or component

Comment: How you are injecting  ServiceGrid class?  annotation is missing  on ServiceGrid

Comment: Does ServiceGrid have any Spring annotation (e.g. Component, Service), because if doesn't it can't be load in Spring Context ?

Comment: Thanks  all for replying, I annotated ServiceGrid  with Service and component indivisiually but both didnt work !!

Comment: Could you show us the stack error you are getting ?

Comment: @LunguDaniel, java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.nokia.nsw.ihub.strategy.ServiceGrid.processRequest(ServiceGrid.java:17)
 at com.nokia.nsw.ihub.service.ServiceTypeResolver.invokeServiceClass(ServiceTypeResolver.java:28)
 at com.nokia.nsw.ihub.controller.BaseController.getBr(BaseController.java:26)

Comment: Even ServiceTypeResolver is annotated with Service annotation,
(at)Service
(at)Slf4j
public class ServiceTypeResolver {
 
 
 public String invokeServiceClass(String  serviceDefinition) {

Comment: @jason , while booting application I am getting value,
2020-04-11 18:13:11.907  INFO 121280 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3234 ms
adapterConfig  Cisco //// Here

Comment: Problem is I am creating object in factory class using new ,
 public IhubStrategy getIhubStrategy(String serviceDefinition) {
  
  System.out.println("IhubStrategyFactory : "+sfg.getAdapterConfig().getSeedEntity());
  
//  IhubStrategy strategy = null;

  if (serviceDefinition.equalsIgnoreCase("serviceGrid")) {

   return new ServiceGrid();

But how to  return object to my resolver class ??
public void invokeServiceClass(String  serviceDefinition) {
  IhubStrategy ihubStrategy = this.ihubFactory.getIhubStrategy(serviceDefinition);

Comment: Added code of my factory class @LunguDaniel, please suggest

Comment: I resolved this scenario using ApplicationContextAware. Thanks all for replying
SpringBeanUtil.getBean(ServiceGrid.class);
////////////////////////////////////////////
public class SpringBeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    
   ..........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate ServiceGrid with @Componenet or @Service, because at this moment it's not load in Spring Context and ServiceGridConfiguration can't be autowired.

```
@Service
public class ServiceGrid implements IhubStrategy {

    @Autowired
    ServiceGridConfiguration sfg;


    @Override
    public void processRequest(String message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ServiceGrid   "+message+"*******"+sfg.getAdapterConfig().getSeedEntity());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lungu, I was missing this annotation at the begining !!!!!

Comment: You are welcome, if you found this answer helpful, please upvote and mark it as helpful. In this way you'll help other persons which have the same problem. Thanks